Form Data is not submitting to LinkedIn Using Python Requests and Selenium
I'm trying to automate updating my LinkedIn profile using Python. I've successfully logged in using Selenium, and now I'm attempting to use the requests library to submit form data for just the "About" section. However, I'm consistently getting a 403 Forbidden error when attempting to submit the form.
Here's what I've done so far:
Login with Selenium:
I can successfully log in to LinkedIn using Selenium and navigate to my profile page.
Extract Cookies and CSRF Token:
I extracted cookies from the Selenium session and obtain the CSRF token from the profile page's HTML.
Submit Form Data with Requests:
I attempted to submit the "About" section form data using the requests library, including cookies and the CSRF token.
But no matter what I change, I keep receiving a 403 Forbidden response.
My code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests
import json
import re

username = 'my_username'
password = 'my_password'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')  # for headless mode
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

def get_cookies(driver):
    return {cookie['name']: cookie['value'] for cookie in driver.get_cookies()}

def extract_csrf_token(html):
    match = re.search(r'name="csrfToken" content="(.*?)"', html)
    return match.group(1) if match else None

def about(session, link, val, csrf_token, headers):
    summary_field_name = 'gai-text-form-component-profileEditFormElement-SUMMARY-profile-ACoAAE9YpSsBDmNZhmxG3ss87KP-i8rqiD6k-gM-summary'
    data = {
        summary_field_name: val,
        'save_button_name': 'Save',
        'csrfToken': csrf_token  
    }
    response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Form submitted successfully!")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to submit form: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)

try:
    driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')
    username_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')
    username_field.send_keys(username)

    password_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password')
    password_field.send_keys(password)

    password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="ember-view block"]'))
    ).click()

    profile_page = driver.current_url
    driver.get(profile_page)
    
    csrf_token = extract_csrf_token(driver.page_source)

    base = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/timmy-scrown-a6399b311/edit/forms/{}/new/?profileFormEntryPoint=PROFILE_COMPLETION_HUB"
    cookies = driver.get_cookies()
    session = requests.Session()

    for cookie in cookies:
        session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Referer': profile_page,
        'X-CSRF-Token': csrf_token,
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }

    sections = {
        "about": "summary",
        "education": "education",
        "positions": "position",
        "career_break": "career-break",
        "skills": "skills",
        "certifications": "certification",
        "projects": "project",
        "courses": "course",
        "volunteer_experience": "volunteer-experience",
        "publications": "publication",
        "patents": "patent",
        "honors_awards": "honor",
        "languages": "language",
        "organizations": "organization",
        "test_scores": "test-score",
        "causes": "causes"
    }

    functions = {
        "about": about,
        "education": education,
        "positions": positions,
        "career_break": career_break,
        "skills": skills,
        "certifications": certifications,
        "projects": projects,
        "courses": courses,
        "volunteer_experience": volunteer_experience,
        "publications": publications,
        "patents": patents,
        "honors_awards": honors_awards,
        "languages": languages,
        "organizations": organizations,
        "test_scores": test_scores,
        "causes": causes
    }

    with open('core.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)

    for key, value in data.items():
        if key in functions:
            link = base.format(sections[key])
            functions[key](session, link, value, csrf_token, headers)
            print(link, key, value)

finally:
    driver.quit()

core.json
{
  "about": "Experienced software engineer with a passion for developing innovative programs.",
  "education": [
    {
      "school": "University of Technology",
      "degree": "Bachelor of Science in Computer Science",
      "field_of_study": "Computer Science",
      "start_year": "2016",
      "end_year": "2020"
    }
  ],
  "positions": [
    {
      "title": "Senior Developer",
      "company": "TechCorp",
      "location": "New York, NY",
      "start_month": "January",
      "start_year": "2021",
      "end_month": "Present",
      "description": "Leading a team of developers to create innovative software solutions."
    }
  ],
  "skills": ["Python", "Java", "JavaScript"],
  "certifications": [
    {
      "name": "Certified Java Developer",
      "issuing_organization": "Oracle",
      "issue_date": "2021-06"
    }
  ]
}

My Error
Failed to submit form: 403
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Unauthorized</title>
        <style>
            html, body, pre {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: Monaco, 'Lucida Console', monospace;
                background: #ECECEC;
            }
            h1 {
                margin: 0;
                background: #333;
                padding: 20px 45px;
                color: #fff;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
                font-size: 28px;
            }
            p#detail {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 15px 45px;
                background: #888;
                border-top: 4px solid #666;
                color: #111;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
                font-size: 14px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Unauthorized</h1>
        <p id="detail">
            You must be authenticated to access this page.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>


Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

The error is at the bottom

That does not tell us where in the code the error happened.  What line of code, exactly, did that html output come from?

The about function or more specifically line 39

Maybe you need to set the user-agent header?  Otherwise the site can easily tell that the post is coming from a robot.

Could you show me an example demonstration of what would work in this context as I wanted the python requests portion to work hand in hand with selenium

Try undetected chromedriver
pip install undetected-chromedriver

does not trigger anti-bot services
import undetected_chromedriver as browser
driver = browser.Chrome()
...


It does not work as the part that is giving an error is the python requests part

The 403 response comes from a requests call, not a selenium call.  This is not the reason.
